# php - json_decode returning NULL

Tags: php, json

I am finding it hard to debug why json_decode is returning null.

Here is a var dump of the JSON I am trying to decode:

```
string(82) " {"total_goals":83,"total_games":30,"average_goals":"2.77"} "
```

Which is valid JSON according to JSONLint.

```
var_dump($homeJSON);  // Returns above 
$json = json_decode($homeJSON); // Decode the json
var_dump($json); // Returns NULL
```

$homeJSON is reading file_get_contents(url) if that makes a difference.

JSON is coming from a file on another site:

```
$post_data = json_encode(array('total_goals' => $totalgoals, 'total_games' =>     $totalgames, 'average_goals' => $average_goals));

echo $post_data;
```

I have checked the BOM and removed it, and I am still getting NULL

Comment: what is the content of your JSON file?

Comment: My guess it is breaks on [the leading BOM](https://hexdump.pieterhordijk.com/b5faf8fb7d13fba709a3156a1901a3c241ae46a0/bom)

Comment: @PeeHaa - can I just use trim() to remove this?

Comment: Where is the json coming from?

Comment: Although [the close dupe is a dupe](https://3v4l.org/ULrdT) imo you should really fix the source to not do stupid shit like sending a BOM character in the first place.

Comment: @PeeHaa  How do I avoid sending a BOM character?

Comment: My educated guess is that your texteditor / IDE saves files with the BOM. You will have to save files as utf8 without bom

Comment: @PeeHaa - its saved as UTF-8 on TextWrangler which is no BOM

Comment: I removed the BOM and still getting NULL